# Firebase database query design

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I have basically a list of entries that many users can read (but can't write). These items show up sorted in the app based on a unique integer that each entry has. I'd like to add a way to allow each individual user to favorite some x number of these items, making those x items appear first in the list. Is there a way I can achieve this using firebase's querying without having to duplicate the list for each user?

Comment: Only half of a solution, but you can store the user favorites under each user, keep storing the list of entries as you do, and then have a custom sort function on the client side that sorts with first priority by user favorites, secondly by the unique integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` and just passing in the query (which is what I was previously doing), I had to manually manage the results and use a `RecyclerView.Adapter` instead. This is the code that I ended up with. I'll clean it up a bit so it actually replaces items if they're already there and update and whatnot, but this is a quick summary of the necessary approach:

```
val data = ArrayList<SomeData>
val favorites = ArrayList<Favorite>
val dataWithFavorites = ArrayList<SomeData>

private val dbRef : DatabaseReference by lazy { FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference }
private val dataQuery : Query by lazy { dbRef.child("data").orderByChild("rank") }
private val favoritesQuery : Query by lazy { dbRef.child("users").child("$someUserId").child("favorites").orderByChild("name") }

init {
    dataQuery.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError?) { }

        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot?) {
            data.clear()
            p0!!.children.mapTo(dataList) { it.getValue(SomeData::class.java)!! }
            updateEntries()       
        }
    })

    favoritesQuery.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError?) { }

        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot?) {
            favorites.clear()
            p0!!.children.mapTo(dataList) { it.getValue(Favorite::class.java)!! } 
            updateEntries()       
        }
    })
}

private fun updateEntries() {
    if (data.isEmpty()) {
        return
    }
    val favoritesStrings = favorites.map { (id) -> id }
    val favoriteData = data
            .filter { favoritesStrings.contains(it.id) }
            .sortedBy { it.name }
            .onEach { it.isFavorite = true }
    dataWithFavorites.clear()
    dataWithFavorites.addAll(data)
    dataWithFavorites.removeAll(favoriteData)
    dataWithFavorites.forEach { it.isFavorite = false }
    dataWithFavorites.addAll(0, favoriteData)
    recyclerView.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```